# jQuery recursive script only works on the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to make myself a jQuery script that adds a box every time I click on a box that was previously made, but it doesn't work the way I expect it to. It adds lots of boxes when I click on the first "CLICK ME" box (which is great), but when I click on other boxes, it doesn't do anything. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            font-family: Avenir;
        }

        h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        .center {
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            width: 380px;
        }

        .box {
            background: #F7F7F7;
            width: 380px;
            height: 80px;
            border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px #BABABA;
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: inherit;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="center">
        <button class="box">CLICK ME</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("button").on("click", function() {
            $(".center").append("<button class=\"box\">CLICK ME</button>");
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax was a bit off, I think that's how it used to work with `live` back in the day, but `on` behaves slightly differently for a better performance. See it in action here:

```js
$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  $(".center").append("<button class=\"box\">CLICK ME</button>");
});
```

```css
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 380px;
}
.box {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  width: 380px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #BABABA;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <button class="box">CLICK ME</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem (I gave you a few points now), I just didn't like what dave did. Welcome to Stack Overflow and good luck with your project! :)

Comment: Thanks again, I'm glad I met someone like you!

Comment: I am happy to delete my answer and upvote yours if you at least mention event delegation and why it is necessary.

Comment: @dave no worries, I don't care about rep points, I just didn't like you asking for the accept. Please keep your answer as well (gave you an upvote). As to why I didn't mention event delegation is because I assumed OP knew about it and that he just used an old jQ syntax that worked for `live`.

Comment: @Shomz fair enough. Sorry about that. +1

Answer (score 1):

Since your new buttons aren't on the page at the time the event is assigned, you need to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  $(".center").append("<button class=\"box\">CLICK ME</button>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that your subsequent buttons do not exist as the DOM is first drawn. You need to go one level up and then have the function look find the next button and therefore execute the code that you want executed.

Your code should look like this:

`$(".center").on("click", "button", function() {
       $(".center").append("<button class=\"box\">CLICK ME</button>");
   });`

Once other buttons are added, any of them will add a new button.